# Is it good UX to wait for all images to be loaded before displaying them?

Tags: website-design, web-app, mobile-application, image

Let's say there's a website or app with 20 images on the initial screen. For websites, we'd typically show images whenever they're available. Since the 20 images will likely all load at different times, the screen will repaint 20 times, once for each image.

I noticed a lot of mobile apps would wait until all the images are ready before showing them all at once. There would be a single repaint. If some images take too long to load, the apps will wait a bit, then show all the images that loaded successfully.

The trade-off is showing some images sooner vs showing everything all at once. Are there studies showing which one users prefer?

Comment: As a user I prefer some sort of lazy loading. Blurred or just appear when it is ready. Otherwise I wonder if the site is broken

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can say whether it is 'good UX' or not unless you know the context in which the images are being displayed.

Obviously if there is no relationship between the images and they don't need to be shown all at once, then giving the user something to see first and less wait time is good when they expect things to being fast.

However, if the images have some connections, or are required for something displayed to make sense, then it is better to wait until they are loaded since the user will still have to wait before they can perform the task required.

Basically it's just another way of saying that the best user experience is one that meets or exceeds the user's expectations.